# Cannot integrate an external jar in a spring boot maven project

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot, maven

I have a local jar which I need to test. This jar has not yet been pushed to maven repository.

I created a sample project and added this jar as an external jar on the classpath by clicking on configure build path.

When I import the class from the jar eclipse is able to import it but when i run Maven build it gives an error saying

com.x.y package does not exist
ClassName.class cannot find symbol

What is going wrong over here ?

Comment: You can add it to the Pom with `<scope>system</scope>`,`<systemPath>${project.basedir}/dir/it/is/in.jar</systemPath>`

Comment: Hi 123, I tried this as well. It says i need to omit this since the dependency is not in system scope. I also tried adding includeSystemscope config to maven boot plugin. But still the same issue

Comment: What says you need to omit it?

Comment: when i do a maven build it fails and gives this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just push it to your local maven repository, this is the command line:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
-DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

Later add this dependency in your pom and it will work.

Comment: Hi, I tried this as well. I crosschecked if the jar file was actually created in the .m2 folder and it was there. I added the dependency and the build was successful. But when i run mvn spring-boot:run , jetty throws an erroe saying unable to start reactive web server no class def found for org/jetty/ServletHolder something like this.

Comment: because you need the jetty starter dependency. It's a different problem.
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

Comment: I have this dependency as well. It still gives me the error. If i remove the maven dependency of my local jar and just run the project. It runs perfectly fine. The problem is integrating the local jar.